# Review System, has_many, belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I sadly encounter the problem, that when I try to create a Review the Product_id stays nil. Whats the cleanest way to fill this in for the product that I want to review?

Reviews_controller

```
def create
@user = current_user
@review = @user.reviews.new(params[:review])
if @review.save
  redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Thank you for your review'
else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

My Product, Review and User are set up with the has_many and belongs_to relationships.

The New View for the Review

```
%h1 Write a Review

= form_for @review do |f|
  %fieldset
    = f.label :review
    = f.text_area :review
  %fieldset
    = f.label :rating
    = f.text_field :rating
  %fieldset
    = f.submit 'Post Review', class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary'
```

I'm aware that I'm not finding the Product - How do I get to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the object through an association use build

```
   @review = @user.reviews.build(params[:review])
```

that will extract the user's id and add it to user_id in your reviews object. I need more information to find the product, you can most likely add a hidden_field in your review form that will have the Products id

```
  <%= hidden_field :product, @product.id %> #not sure how you are currently finding your product
```

Comment: Yes, but it still leaves the product_id blank. I'm aware that I actually somehow have to specify that, but if I do it with @product = Product.find(params[:id]) I simply get an 'Couldn't find Product without an ID' Error

Comment: Post the code for your view where you are creating the review, I have no information on how you are finding the product

Comment: a review should belong_to :product and Product should :has_many :reviews. You need to have a Product controller with CRUD actions and then render the review partial on each show page for the product

Comment: This spits out    undefined method `merge' for 3:Fixnum

Comment: Fixed it by adding value: @product.id